# IOException "Socket is closed: Unknown socket_descriptor" using java.net.DatagramSocket with Google App Engine

Tags: java, sockets, google-app-engine

I am using `java.net.DatagramSocket` to send UDP packets to a statsd server from a Google App Engine servlet. This generally works; however, we periodically see the following exception:

```
IOException - Socket is closed: Unknown socket_descriptor..
```

When these IOExceptions occur, calling `DatagramSocket.isClosed()` returns `false`.

This issue happens frequently enough that it is concerning, and although I've put in place some workarounds (allocate a new socket and use a DeferredTask queue to retry), it would be good to understand the underlaying reason for these errors.

The [Google docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/) mention, "Sockets may be reclaimed after 2 minutes of inactivity; any socket operation keeps the socket alive for a further 2 minutes." It is unclear to me how this would play into UDP datagrams; however, one suspicion I have is that this is related to GAE instance lifecycle in some way.

My code (sanitized and extracted) looks like:

```
DatagramSocket _socket;

void init() {
    _socket = new DatagramSocket();
}

void send() {
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(<BYTES>, <LENGTH>, <HOST>, <PORT>); 
    _socket.send(packet);
}
```

Appreciate any feedback on this!

Comment: 'I have read about some aggressive timeout management of `DatagramSockets`' where?

Comment: The word 'timeout' does not appear on the page you cited. Are you referring to the ['Daily Data and Per-Minute (Burst) Data Limits'](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas?hl=en#Sockets)?

Comment: The words 'reclamation' and 'idle' don't appear on that page either. What are you talking about?

Comment: I see. When you put a word into quotation marks it means it is a literal quotation. It wasn't. The mechanism by which sockets are 'reclaimed' isn't specified, but outright closure is as plausible as anything else.

Comment: As I noted, when this exception occurs `isClosed()` returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach taken to workaround this issue was simply to manage a single static DatagramSocket instance with a couple of helper methods, `getSocket()` and `releaseSocket()` to release sockets throwing IOExceptions through the release method, and then allocate upon next access through the get method. Not shown in this code is retry logic to retry the failed socket.send(). Under load testing, this seems to work reliably.

```
try {

    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(<BYTES>, <LENGTH>, <HOST>, <PORT>);

    getSocket().send(packet);

} catch (IOException ioe) {

    releaseSocket();

}
```